# Salesforce bulk API: How to set a date to null

Tags: python, salesforce

I am writing some python code to set some dates to null. According to the documentation, anything that needs to be set to null, will have to contain #N/A on the csv its picking up the data from. However this does not seem to work for date fields. I get the following error:

SalesforceMalformedRequest: Malformed request https://na131.salesforce.com/services/async/38.0/job/7504O00000LKUpIQAX/batch/7514O00000SWAzPQAX/result. Response content: {'exceptionCode': 'InvalidBatch', 'exceptionMessage': 'Records not processed'}

I made sure the field shows up as nillable on workbench as well.

How can I set an existing date to null? Any help is appreciated

Comment: How are you calling the Bulk API? Are you using `simple_salesforce` or `salesforce_bulk`? Can you share an example of your Python?

Comment: Hey I am using simple_salesforce, more specifically the sf.bulk.Account.update method which takes a list of dicts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`simple_salesforce` does not use the CSV-format Bulk API (even if the underlying data is sourced from a CSV file). See [`bulk.py`](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/blob/master/simple_salesforce/bulk.py#L88):

```
payload = {
    'operation': operation,
    'object': object_name,
    'contentType': 'JSON'
}
```

In the JSON version of the Bulk API, fields to be nulled [must be set to `null` in JSON](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/datafiles_xml_valid_records.htm?search_text=null):

> To specify a null value in JSON, set the field value to null. For example, `"description" : null`

Do so in Python by setting the relevant property to `None`.

Comment: Hey thanks for this! I tried using None and exporting to JSON. Looks like it worked as intended!